# Makefile implicit rules with function calls in dependencies

Tags: makefile

I'm using Make to organize my data analysis, and I have multiple input data sets, each of which can be analyzed against a reference data set.  Of course, each of those datasets requires their own special bit of pre-processing.  What I'd like is to have an implicit rule that can parse out the relatively simple directory structure, and use that to understand which prerequisites to make, so for instance, if I wanted to run:

```
make ref1/sample1_processed ref1/sample2_processed ref2/sample1_processed #...etc
```

I could have an implicit rule that looks something like:

```
%_processed: $(dir %)/preprocessed samples/$(notdir %)_preprocessed
     process_data --reference $(dir $*)/preprocessed --sample samples/$(notdir $*)_preprocessed
```

which ideally make could interpret as:

```
ref1/sample1_processed -> (ref1/preprocessed, samples/sample1_preprocessed)
ref1/sample2_processed -> (ref1/preprocessed, samples/sample2_preprocessed)
ref2/sample1_processed -> (ref2/preprocessed, samples/sample1_preprocessed)
```

(where -> would mean depends on).

What seems to be happening, though, is that the function calls fail in the dependency line (they seem to do just fine in the recipe itself).

Here's a minimal non-working sample that I think communicates what I'd like to have happen:

```
%_processed: $(dir %)/preprocessed samples/$(notdir %)_preprocessed
    echo $(dir $*)
    echo $(notdir $*)
    echo "Done"

samples/%_preprocessed: samples/%
    touch $@

%/preprocessed: | %
    touch $@


ref%:
    mkdir $@
```

and from the command line:

```
$ mkdir samples/
$ touch samples/sample1 samples/sample2
$ make ref1/sample1_processed
make: *** No rule to make target `ref1/sample1_processed'.  Stop.
```

But if you comment out the dependencies of %_processed, it does run properly (albeit without checking for said dependencies):

```
$ make ref1/sample1_processed
echo ref1/
ref1/
echo sample1
sample1
echo "Done"
Done
```

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into one of the great weak spots of Make: its primitive handling of wildcards. Using two wildcards in one rule would be the logical solution, but it's impossible... Well, difficult.

There's more than one way to solve this, but I'd use [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) and pull the desired variables out of the target name:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

sample%_processed: samples/$$(subst processed,preprocessed,$$(notdir $$@)) $$(dir $$@)preprocessed
    process_data --reference $(dir $@)preprocessed --sample $<
```

(Notice that there's more than one way to construct the command; getting the first prereq with `$<` is much easier than getting the second, so I've made the ugly one the first.)